# Hi...Shouldn't the id_public variable give the result as 81 & 86? Why is it taking up different memory locations for both the derive classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
    public:
    int id_public;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
    public:
    void setId(int id) {
        id_public = id;
        cout<<id_public<<endl;
    }
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
    public:
    void setId2(int id) {
        cout<<id_public<<endl;
        id_public += id;
        cout<<id_public<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Child1 obj1;
    Child2 obj2;

    obj1.setId(81);
    obj2.setId2(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don’t `#include` anything from `bits/`.

Comment: Recommend moving the question from the title to the question. In addition, `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard header and should not be used ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)). `using namespace std;` should be avoided ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). When you combine the two the odds of you encountering problems rises dramatically.

Comment: Why do you think obj2,id_public should be 86?   Why do you think the two instances (obj1.id_public and obj2.id_public) should occupy the same memory?

Comment: @2785528: "id_public" is the feature of the parent class. So, when child1 and child2 are inheriting the "id_public" feature, I'm thinking both the child class and the parent class should have the same copy of that feature with same memory location.....where did my thinking go wrong?

Comment: In C++, each child instance has it's own parent instance.  So the two parents are distinct, and that explains why they occupy different memory.

Comment: @2785528: Is it just a C++ feature or an OPP feature! I mean, does it differ in case of Java?

Comment: @JoydwipMohajon - I do not know Java.

Comment: @2785528: Thanks BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s nothing to do with two *classes*: you just have two *objects*, each with its own member variables.  A variable has to be `static` to be shared (which is rarely needed).

Comment: Also, in `obj2`, the member `id_public` has not been initialized.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Well, yes—they’re separate variables *and* there’s undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavisHerring: "id_public" is the feature of the parent class. So, when child1 and child2 are inheriting the "id_public" feature, I'm thinking both the child class and the parent class should have the same copy of that feature with same memory location.....where did my thinking go wrong?

Comment: @JoydwipMohajon: The *classes* do share just one member variable, but two objects even of *one* class share none of their (non-`static`, again) member variables.  Being of different, related classes won’t make them share *more*.